# Image source in html file

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, dom

I tried to put a picture in an HTML file. If I put them using for example background-image: url('file:///C:/Users/faycel/Desktop/site%20guide/paris.jpg'); it works However when I tried another link for a picture it doesn't work. The problem is what can I do when I will put my website online.No image will appear since this link work only in my computer I thinked about google drive so I put some pictures that I will use in my website in google drive but when I used the links I didn't get any picture on my web page (all the pictures were public in my drive)
PS: I used the method ./images/logo.png" but in vain .

Comment: You must understand what's HTML and image tag / css background-images can do for you. Your image must be in the server to see it. If you can't upload them to the server, think about imgur site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to reference images and other documents with HTML: with absolute linking and with relational linking. A good practice is to have an ordered folder estructure and reference with relational URLs.

For instance, you can have a main directory where you store all your html files and sub-directories for your images, css stylesheets, scripts and so on. Using this folder estructure, you'd reference your image with `img/paris.jpg`, where img is the containing folder for all your images.

This way, when you upload all your files, nothing will break.

For more infor, visit the W3C documentation: http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970917/htmlweb.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

The link "file:///C:/Users/faycel/Desktop/site%20guide/paris.jpg" calls the image in your computer. Try with the public URL of the file in Google Drive.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, you just need to put an absolute link in your image.

For example..

If your website have an img directory you can use

`<img src="http://www.example.com.br/img/img.png"/>`

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

Comment: If if helped you, Thumbs up to stay at top please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative links.

1. Create a folder named images on the same location where html file is
2. Add all images to this directory
3. Instead of full path like `c:/something/something/images/fil.png` just use `images/fil.png`
4. When uploading the website also upload the images folder and it's contents

This fixes your problem. But don't forget to read  tutorials about IMG tag and its SRC attribute.

Comment: When the html file is in a sub folder of where the images folder is located you can use `./images/file.png` when it is a sub folder of sub folder use `././images/fil.png`

Comment: Thank you for your answer !